# UITextView ContentInset

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to stop my text view content 60px before the right edge, because I have a CLEAR button and some other things on the right side. So this is what I'm doing.

```
TextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 60)
```

But now, when I open up the keyboard and start typing, it just stops showin letters 60px before the end. Then the cursor jumps to the next line and some letters are invisible. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post a video of the behavior you're facing?

Comment: Why you change the contentInset and not the textView size?

Comment: @MartinVidic I'm not sure about your question.
Do you want textview don't jump to the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using textContainerInset instead of contentInset fixed the problem